# Throttle Camel Requests based on query param

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel route like below:-

`from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/orchestratorservice").process(processor);`

`from("direct:setStatusToReadyToShip").to("bean:orderHelper?method=setStatusToReadyToShip")`

I have gone through the [throttle](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html) pattern. But is there a way I can get rate limit / throttle based on a query / header param(e.g if debug=1 is set in request then we want to throttle requests to 10 req/sec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using the Predicate. Below code worked for me:-

```
Predicate isDebug = header("debug").isEqualTo("true");
from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/orchestratorservice")     
.choice()
    .when(isDebug).throttle(5).timePeriodMillis(1000).rejectExecution(true).process(processor)
.endChoice()
.otherwise()
   .process(processor);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes its do-able, but a bit more complicated that you would initially assume.  Technically this is a duplicate question so I will just provide the link below:

[Apache Camel - Dynamically changing throttle values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840382/apache-camel-dynamically-changing-throttle-values)

Basically the short version is you have to leverage a jmx call that camel sets up.  In Camel 2.16+ this is much easier.  However, there is a not so convenient work around available in Camel 2.15 listed as well.  Best of luck on your project!